# In dreamweaver svn, what's the diff between 'check out files' and 'get latest versions'?

Tags: svn, dreamweaver

I'm using dreamweaver to do with a svn server.
I don't know which dreamweaver command corresponding to the svn command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "check out" refers to the traditional use of the term check out with Revision control, as this line describes from Wikipedia:

> Once one developer "checks out" a file, others can read that file, but
>   no one else may change that file until that developer "checks in" the
>   updated version (or cancels the checkout).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control#File_locking

Also, this line seems to indicate that:

> Note: You can also either right-click a file and choose Check Out from
>   the context menu, or select the file and click the Check Out button to
>   get the latest version. Because SVN does not support a check-out
>   workflow, however, this action does not actually check out the file in
>   the traditional sense.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Dreamweaver/10.0_Using/WS80FE60AC-15F8-45a2-842E-52D29F540FED.html

Since SVN doesn't have this kind of check-out concept ( it does have the similar lock concept - http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.locking.html), Get latest version is the equivalent of SVN update / checkout ( on existing working copy)